# Disable window effects for one specific application

Tags: effects

I have one application that has a couple of areas that auto-hide and pop up again as soon as I hover over an area. These poping up areas seem to be implemented as some kind of window, and they pop up with the fancy effect I have configured for any other window. I like that fancy desktop animations, but don't like them to appear for this specific application.

My question: Is there any way of turning off those effects for one specific application?